# Enclosure Escape and object seeking

Tags: ros, irobot-create, turtlebot, object-recognition, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all , Can i get the code in these [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFMgxZvUDOs&list=PLDC89965A56E6A8D6) about ROS in roswiki ?

these vedios attached in Beginner Level ROS Tutorial Video Demos at ANU [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58375/enclosure-escape-and-object-seeking/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-17**:
The video is posted by Usman Qayyum. Please send him an email: usman.qayyum at anu.edu.au  And let us know when he replies :-)

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-03-18**:
i have sent to him a message :) ,, but i asked here wishing anyone did this application before :D

once he reply i 'll let you know ISA

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-03-18**:
check the link in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://usmanqayyum.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/turtlebot-navigation-report-and-code.html

---

Originally posted by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) with karma: 464 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-22**:
Hmmm... I read the C++ code in the link but it contains only a Class TurtlebotTeleop which is not doing the autonomous navigation and object searching. Not the right code...

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-03-22**:
i read the report ,, it depends on measure the max distance from the sensors and the kinect to determine the way to exit from enclosure ,, when press Up keyboard key it begins to circlinig to calculate the max distance and begin to move ,, but still rosmake the pack give me errors in matcher.h code

**Comment by [usman](https://answers.ros.org/users/4430/usman/) on 2013-06-27**:
Hi chik, Turtlebot Teleop is the wrapper main class used in the project. The report describes the algorithm (in simple its a state-machine implementation), checking different conditions. The matcher.h has to do with ros distribution (esp. opencv), as the project is developed under ros-electric.